# In VSCode, can you edit the list of available devices to remove a device?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This is pertaining to a Flutter application.

For example, the device list in the lower right corner is on 'Windows'. I do not want Windows to be in this list as I solely run on Chrome when testing locally and then on an Android device when testing on device.

Comment: This question should be addressed to a VS-Code appropriate help forum

Comment: @itprorh66 this is a valid question. go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288832/11107541 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337024/11107541

Comment: @starball thanks! I have no idea how I didn't find that post originally. I'll close this.